# What is the intersection point of functions $f(x) = 8x^2$; $g(x) = 64x \log x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I tried to solve this equation by hand without success. I used wolframalpha and the solution in the plot is (26.09, 5446.96). I just want to solve this equation step by step. Thanks in advance, cheers :D[Plot wolframalpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7egx.png)

Comment: Does "$\log$" mean base $e$ or base $10$ ?

Comment: OK, your plot shows that it is base $e$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer from @Pedro,
$$8x^2 = 64x\log x$$
is undefined if $x=0$, so
$$\frac x8 = \log x$$
$$e^\frac x8 = x$$
$$-\frac18 = -\frac18 x e^{-\frac18 x}$$
Now we can use Lambert's W function, also called the Product Log, which is the inverse of $xe^x$ :
$$W\left(-\frac18\right) = -\frac18 x$$
$$x = -8 W\left(-\frac18\right)$$
The W function has several branches (like the square root, positive or negative). From WolframAlpha, the two solutions are
$$x_1 = -8*\text{ProductLog}[-1, -1/8] \approx 26.09$$
$$x_2 = -8*\text{ProductLog}[0, -1/8] \approx 1.15$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute the real numbers $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$, and then the intersection points are given by pairs $(x,f(x))$ for such real numbers $x$. The equation to solve is:

$8x^{2}=64x\log{x}$

The logarithm is not defined for $x=0$, so we may disregard that value of $x$ and obtain the new equation (also dividing by $8$):

$x=8\log{x}$

Now taking exponentials:

$e^{x}=x^{8}$

An equation of this type has no solution by hand: it is a **transcendental equation**. So the best think you can do, in my opinion, is to use some numerical method to compute the solution. For example, asking Wolfram Alpha as you already did.

Comment: You could use the Lambert W function: $$e^{x/8} = x$$ $$-\frac18 = -\frac18 x e^{-\frac18 x}$$ $$W(-\frac18) = -\frac18 x$$ $$-8 W(-\frac18) = x$$

Comment: That doesn't help at all to find the value of $x$ by hand, does it?

Comment: What if the answer was something like $e^3$ ? Does that count as a solution "by hand"? Or do we need a decimal approximation?

Comment: I would call that a solution by hand, but I don't think you can find such a solution either: $e^{3}$ is not equal to 24

Comment: Where did $24$ come from? I didn't mean that $e^3$ is a solution to this particular problem; it was just for example. My point is that $W(x)$ is a valid function, just like $\exp(x)$, so $W(-1/8)$ is as good as $\exp(3)$.

Comment: I agree with $e^{3}$ being a solution by hand but not with $W(3)$ being a solution by hand, because $e$ is an everyday number in math but $W$ is a function (or better said a notation) which is defined precisely to solve this kind of equations. My point is that you are just restating the problem with new words. But I don't think this is a serious discussion, it's rather subjective. You are right in that you can write the solution in terms of the function $W$. It was a useful remark in any case, so thank you for mentioning it. Maybe the OP does find it a satisfactory solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, I thought this equation was easier to solve. Your answer is right but for me it's more easier to understand the answer of @claude-leibovici, because my background of math is not so deep.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use Lambert function, consider that you look for the zeros of
$$f(x)=x-8\log(x)$$ $$f'(x)=1-\frac 8x$$ $$f''(x)=\frac 8{x^2} >0 \qquad \forall x$$

The first derivative cancels for $x=8$ and $f(8)=8-8\log(8)\approx -8.63553 <0$. So, there are two roots, the first lower than $8$, the second larger than $8$.

By inspection $f(1)=1$ and this could be a good starting point for Newton method (without any overshoot of the solution - by Darboux theorem). Then, for the first root, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.000000000 \\
 1 & 1.142857143 \\
 2 & 1.155291477 \\
 3 & 1.155370822 \\
 4 & 1.155370825
\end{array}
\right)$$ For the second root, let us start using $x_0=16$ and get as iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 16.00000000 \\
 1 & 28.36141956 \\
 2 & 26.13113396 \\
 3 & 26.09349745 \\
 4 & 26.09348548
\end{array}
\right)$$ Notice that could could have a better starting point using Taylor series around the minimum
$$f(x)=(8-8 \log (8))+\frac{1}{16} (x-8)^2+O\left((x-8)^3\right)$$ which will give as approximation 
$$x_0=8 \left(1+\sqrt{2 (\log (8)-1)}\right)\approx 19.7545$$ but will not seriously affect the path to the solution.